# Insert RowData in MySql Table using Trigger After Update

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am running MySQL 5.6. I want to know which row/rows have been updated in a table. One way is to create a trigger using PHPMyAdmin. This trigger can store row id (id is be a table column) of that row and current datetime into another table. This way I will know which record has changed. In PhpMyAdmin when I add trigger it asks me event, time and table which I filled. But what do I write in Definition & Definer.

Comment: I avoid using wizards because they aren't transportable across IDEs but I'm guessing definition is where you put your code to insert to another table. Insert...values (new.col1,new.col2 etc)

Comment: I don't know what code to put. For e.g. how to value of column id for row which got updated.

Comment: Actually I gave you the code in my comment perhaps you should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Since I am using PHPMyAdmin, I do not know if I need to write Create Trigger ...etc. Maybe only code that gives me the value of record being updated and ability to insert in another table. I saw the link you have shared but didn't understand how to go about it.